# how to increase input text box size in react-autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs

how to increase the size of input tag in react-autocomplete package?
i didn't know how to change the input box size because there is no clear documentation regarding that?
[here is the link of react-autocomplete package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autocomplete-custom-input)

**Example**

```
<Autocomplete
  getItemValue={(item) => item.label}
  items={[
    { label: 'apple' },
    { label: 'banana' },
    { label: 'pear' }
  ]}
  renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) =>
    <div style={{ background: isHighlighted ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }}>
      {item.label}
    </div>
  }
  value={value}
  onChange={(e) => value = e.target.value}
  onSelect={(val) => value = val}
/>
```

this code automatically creates one input box of some size my question is how to resize the input box size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can use a combination of the following props to affect `input` style: `inputProps`, `wrapperStyle`.

```
<Autocomplete
   {...props}
   inputProps={{ style: { width: 100% } }}
   wrapperStyle={ width: 1000 }
/>
```