# How to style react autocomplete input box?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

I am trying to use react-autocomplete in my component. Everything is working fine results are shown. But I am not able to style the default input box. 
this is autocomplete

```
<Autocomplete 
getItemValue={this.getItemValue}
items={this.state.autocompleteData}
renderItem={this.renderItem}
value={this.state.value}
onChange={this.onChange}
onSelect={this.onSelect} 
menuStyle={menuStyle}
/>
```

style for dropdown menu is working fine.

```
const menuStyle = {
  borderRadius: '3px',
  boxShadow: '0 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
  background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
  padding: '2px 0',
  fontSize: '90%',
  position: 'fixed',
  overflow: 'auto',
  maxHeight: '50%', // TODO: don't cheat, let it flow to the bottom
  "zIndex": 100,
};
```

i tried to add style as per answer in this question but it's not working.
[how to increase input text box size in react-autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388571/how-to-increase-input-text-box-size-in-react-autocomplete)

How to add style to input box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object given to prop [`inputProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete#inputprops-object-optional) is used as props for the input, so you can give an object with a `style` property containing your `menuStyles` to that.

```
<Autocomplete
  getItemValue={this.getItemValue}
  items={this.state.autocompleteData}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  onSelect={this.onSelect}
  inputProps={{ style: menuStyle }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inputProps={{ style: menuStyle }}
```

or you can do

```
 styling={
  borderRadius: '3px',
  boxShadow: '0 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
  background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
  padding: '2px 0',
  fontSize: '90%',
  position: 'fixed',
  overflow: 'auto',
  maxHeight: '50%', // TODO: don't cheat, let it flow to the bottom
  "zIndex": 100,
  }
```